# Break down ... にはならない

Tags: particles, particle-に, grammar

The context of my question is the usage of a grammar point from a JLPT 文法 textbook. It is not the grammar point itself that I am asking about, but rather the grammar used to explain the grammar point. Sorry for this complexity.

The textbook explains how to form sentences using the pattern 「〜（の）なら...」:

> 普通形（ナ形 <s>だ</s>／-である・名 <s>だ</s>／-である）＋（の）なら
> ナ形 <s>だ</s>、名 <s>だ</s>の場合は「のなら」**にはならない**

(Basically, the second line is saying that if ~ is a na-adjective or a noun, for instance 雨, one can have 雨なら, or 雨であるなら, or 雨であるのなら, but NOT 雨**の**なら.)

**My question is this.** How to break down the にはならない in bold font in the second line above? I think it could be one (or neither) of the following possibilities:

1. Is it just the negative of ...になる, with は in にはならない being there for emphasis? If so, what exactly does になる mean in this context? To become? To be?
2. Alternatively, does ならない here mean "must not"? If so, what exactly is the usage of には here?

Comment: Allow me to reveal the answer that it's #1, but what do you mean by "what exactly does になる mean"? Does it become weird if you translate it with your suggested words?

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth Thank you very much for the answer. "X becomes Y" implies a change from "X wasn't Y" to "X is now Y". So I can understand it when 大人になる is translated as "to become an adult". There is a change from being a child to being an adult. If「のなら」にはならない is translated as "does not become のなら", I would then wonder what it is that does not change. I suspect that "to become" does not exactly correspond to になる, because generally there is no one-to-one correspondence between the vocabularies of two languages. To a Japanese speaker, is the になる in 大人になる similar to になる in 「のなら」にはならない?